# Java URL not fetching entire source

Tags: java, url

I'm trying to create a simple project where the user inputs a URL and I fetch the relevant information (author, title, etc.) for a citation. The problem is that the Java URL library doesn't seem to fetch the entire page source. For example, I'll use the link https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/jo.html as a reference. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class URLTester 
{
  private static URL url;
  public URLTester(URL u)
  {
      url = u;
  }

  public static ArrayList <String> getContents() throws Exception
  {
         BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
         String inputLine;
         ArrayList <String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
         while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
         {
              arr.add(inputLine);
         }

         in.close();
         return arr;
  }

 public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception
 {
   url = new URL("https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/jo.html");
   ArrayList<String> contents = getContents();
   for(int i = 0; i < contents.size(); i++)
   {
     System.out.println((contents.get(i)));

   }


 }
}
```

This fetches what appears to be a shortened version of the page source for the target. When I pressed 'view page source' on the site, a much more expanded version came up, including information such as the date and the author of the article. I can't paste the source here, because it'll exceed the character limit. How can I get the entire page source, instead of a shortened version?

Comment: check if your console character limit exceed

Comment: @samabcde I feel stupid for asking, but how would I do that?

Comment: Are you using eclipse?

Comment: @samabcde Yes I am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to console character limit exceed.
The default limit is 80000 character in Eclipse.
To change the preference, go to Window -> Preference.
Then find Run/Debug in Left Menu. 
Then open and choose Console.
Uncheck "Limit console output" or increase the limit as you want.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this fixed this for me